# Grails NotSerializableException on POST request

Tags: java, spring, exception, grails, serialization

i keep getting this error when trying to run my grails application can anyone tell what could be the problem.

Here is the method of the controller that causes this error and it gets its parameter through ajax call from a select in the view.

```
    def optionsBySelection()
        {
            log.error "hej11 ${params}"
            Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
            Map query = [params: params]
                def optSelection = sql.rows("select distinct :params from log_entry",query).each { row->
                    log.error "hej22 ${row}"
            }

                render (template: "selection" , model: [optSelection]) as JSON
}




ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NotSerializableException occurred when processing request: [POST] /admin/optionsBySelection - parameters:
params: host
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap. Stacktrace follows:
Message: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap
    Line | Method
->> 1183 | writeObject0          in java.io.ObjectOutputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    347 | writeObject           in     ''
|   4401 | setSerializableObject in com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement
|   4083 | setObject             in     ''
|    169 | setObject . . . . . . in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement
|     34 | optionsBySelection    in se.su.it.monitor.AdminController
|    195 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put the entire `GrailsParameterMap` instance into a prepared SQL query. You cannot do that and should instead create a new map with the subset of parameters that you want to pass to the SQL query.

Comment: i didn't get it. what am trying to pass to the query is one parameter which is string value. thanks for the help